# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED при удалении динамического массива

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Пытаюсь реализовать сортировку слиянием без рекурсии. Набросал алгоритм, проверил на нескольких вариантах входных данных. Сортировка сама по себе работает, но код выбрасывает ошибку при попытке удаления временного массива.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

void mergeSort(int array[], size_t arraySize) {
    int *newArray = new int[arraySize];
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        newArray[i] = array[i];
    }

    size_t size = 1;
    while (size < arraySize) {
        size_t currentPos = 0;
        for (int startPos = 0; startPos < arraySize; startPos += 2 * size) {
            size_t left = startPos, right = startPos + size;
            if (right >= arraySize) {           // если у левой части массива нет "пары" для сравнения
                break;
            }

            while (left < startPos + size && right < (startPos + 2 * size) && right < arraySize) {
                if (array[left] <= array[right]) {
                    newArray[currentPos] = array[left];
                    left++;
                }
                else {
                    newArray[currentPos] = array[right];
                    right++;
                }
                currentPos++;
            }

            // если left/right дошёл до границы, добавляем оставшиеся элементы из другой части массива
            while (left < startPos + size) {
                newArray[currentPos] = array[left];
                currentPos++;
                left++;
            }
            while (right < (startPos + 2 * size)) {
                newArray[currentPos] = array[right];
                currentPos++;
                right++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            array[i] = newArray[i];
        }
        size *= 2;
    }

    delete[] newArray;      // ЗДЕСЬ ВЫБРАСЫВАЕТСЯ ОШИБКА
}


int main() {
    int array[]{8,7,0,3,6,4,7,1,9,3,2};
    mergeSort(array, std::size(array));
    for (int i = 0; i < std::size(array); i++) {
        std::cout << array[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Самое интересное, что при сортировке массива, размер которого является степенью двойки, программа выполняется без ошибок. Искренне не понимаю, где умудрился тут напортачить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Боже. Стоило только отчаяться и полезть с вопросом в интернет, как через несколько минут сошло озарение, где допустил ошибку.

`while (right < (startPos + 2 * size)) {`
Границу воображаемого подмассива проверил, а вот реального массива - проманал. Исправлено:
`while (right < (startPos + 2 * size) && right < arraySize) {`

Проблема решена.

Answer (score 0):

Руками звать `new` и `delete` - не комильфо. Меняем `new` на `std::vector<int> newArray(arraySize);`, а `delete` убираем совсем.

Включаем проверку границ контейнеров (`-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` на GCC, на других компиляторах/стандартных библиотеках гуглите).

Получаем ошибку о выходе за границы:

```
Error: attempt to subscript container with out-of-bounds index 11, but 
container only holds 11 elements.
```

Теперь отладчиком смотрим, на какой строке она вылезла.